# How to insert a blank line in XSL-FO properly?

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I am trying to figure out how to do that properly. I tried to use processing instructions in the code but it seems they are somehow ignored at all.

In the text:

```
end of a paragraph.<?linebreak?></p>
```

As for templating, I tried:

```
<xsl:template match="processing-instruction('linebreak')">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <fo:leader/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

Or simply for testing purposes:

```
<xsl:template match="processing-instruction('linebreak')">
    <fo:block>XXXX</fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

No matters what I do, the template is never used.

I use it inside an eXist-db app (3.0RC1) but I think this is not associated with eXist-db. There is FOP 1.1. I am not sure about the Saxon version.

Comment: As the template is never executed, it seems the first problem is an XSLT one; however, it will be difficult to solve without knowing the rest of the stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to provide more reasonable sample. The problem is it is a part of a larger project.

Comment: Both of the answers below are correct. The *best* answer to you question is not inserting them in the first place, they should (almost must) be handled by the XSL FO engine using space (the first answer). Only in this way will they be appropriately treated and collapsed when they should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No matters what I do, the template is never used.

Concerning this part of the problem, a possible explanation is that the template matching the parent element (`<p>` in your examples) **silently ignores processing instructions when applying templates**.

For example, this quasi-identity stylesheet ignores processing instructions when elements are processed, so their matching template is never executed:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="* | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- this only processes elements, attributes and text nodes! -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="* | @* | text()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="processing-instruction('linebreak')">
    XXXXX
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In order for the processing instructions to be taken into account, the template matching elements must **explicitly** apply templates to them too:

```
  <xsl:template match="* | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="* | @* | text() | processing-instruction()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Note that **using `<xsl:apply-templates/>` would not work** too, as it does not select processing instructions nor attributes, just elements and text nodes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is, of course, technically the answer. However, Hobbes was right about the fact it could be better to use some rendition instruction instead.

Answer (score 3):

Traditionally, you don't insert a line break at the end of a paragraph. Instead, you specify e.g. space-below="12pt" on the fo:block that contains the paragraph.

A line break is always inserted, even if you don't want it (e.g. when the paragraph is placed at the bottom of a page and the line break would wrap to the next page. The space-below can be made conditional, so this space will be collapsed if it appears at the bottom of a page. This results in a better-looking layout.

Comment: Thank you, you are right with the idea behind—why to use processing instruction in the case I need some rendition instruction!